# Ionic Bluetooth BLE read message all the time

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I want read data from sensor by bluetooth all the time. I follow from documentation but I can't set my phone read data from sensor by bluetooth. First i connect mobile with sensor next I add notification by:

```
 this.ble.startNotification(peripheral.id,SERVICE_UUID,
                                CHARACTERISTIC_UUID).subscribe(
      data => {this.onChange(data);}
    )
```

where onChane(data) is :

```
 onChange(buffer :ArrayBuffer){
    console.log("onChange method")
    var data = new Float32Array(buffer);
    console.log(data[0]);   }
```

Next I

```
this.ble.read(peripheral.id,SERVICE_UUID,CHARACTERISTIC_UUID).then(
      (data) => {this.onChange(data);},
      (err) => {console.log(err);}
    )
```

I have failed in this.ble.read. CHARACTERISTIC_UUID and SERVICE_UUID are const. What is wrong? How can I correct this that my phone received datas all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using notifications, you don't need to read the characteristic's value. Once you subscribe for notifications, the peripheral will notify you with the new value whenever the value changes. It looks like your onChange function does this.

If your characteristic supports the read property, you can optionally read the value. Look at the [peripheral data](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#peripheral-data) returned to the connect success callback to see the characteristic properties.

Take a look at my [Ionic BLE example code](https://github.com/don/ionic-ble-examples). The [thermometer example](https://github.com/don/ionic-ble-examples/blob/master/thermometer) connects to a peripheral, subscribes for notifications, and reads the value one time so IU can update the UI with the current value. See https://github.com/don/ionic-ble-examples/blob/d0acd2b47ea08011be4d1aa844c4f74426a22273/thermometer/src/pages/detail/detail.ts#L37-L55